# To protect mp4/mp3 file from copying

Tags: security, multimedia

How protect mp4/mp3 file from copying but must be able to normally be opened to play ?
(if known primarily in NAND memory media filesystem to be shown point of their capabilities)

Comment: I can't quite understand what you mean by "(if known primarily in NAND memory media filesystem to be shown point of their capabilities)", please reformulate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can read a file (play it back/open it), you can copy it.

You can encrypt the file (DRM) and require the user to use a proprietary player to open the file, but even that is not 100% protection, because a clever user will either extract the decryption key from the player, or will capture the decrypted file stream from memory as it’s played back. Finally, they could simply hook up a digital recorder to the sound output of their computer and capture the audio that way. Similarly for video, they can capture the HDMI audio/video signals; in fact that’s how early BluRay pirating efforts started.

The bottom line is, DRM (Digital Rights Management) is inherently broken and is a misapplication of cryptography.

Comment: Yes DRM can (sort of) work for video if you control the full chain of hardware. But attempts to create industry wide drm fail because *someone* always leaks the keys https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/cordcutters/comments/zttju/has_anyone_cracked_the_drm_thats_built_into_hdmi/ Audio is to easy to ge clean analogue recordings.

Comment: I suppose instead of DRM (encryption), you could just make it highly inconvenient to copy the file. Some web streamers split the video file into hundreds of tiny pieces and use the web player to play them in sequence. You can download these pieces, but then you need a tool to concatenate them together properly, without breaking the video, which only certain skilled users can do... DRM or no DRM, at best you’ll only be able to “discourage” people from copying the media, and not fully preventing them from doing so.

Comment: @RoubenTchakhmakhtchian no matter how you slice the original files, the analogue loophole will always exist.

Answer (score 1):

The short version is that this is **very hard** and always involves encrypting the files and preventing users from finding the decryption key.

Attempts to do this at an industry level ([DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management)) have repeatedly failed (Eg: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeCSS), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AACS_encryption_key_controversy) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection)) because someone has always managed to "find" the private key.  Once *someone* find's the key and publishes it, *everybody* can then use it to decrypt and copy files.

It's particularly tricky with cross-industry solutions because multiple (often very many) different corporations need access to the same private key.  It only needs one employee to steal the shared key and the whole system is screwed.

If you are looking for a smaller scale solution, then there are options, **but there is no magic bullet**.

---

**What you cannot do**

Ultimately if you want to play sound, then you can't stop someone recording the sound you play.  If you are playing HDMI, SPDIF or other digital connections, you can't prevent someone taking *[near] perfect* recordings.  High quality analogue recording is always possible.

You also can't prevent someone tampering with hardware and de-soldering chips from the board, or adding in other components.  At some points the file must be decrypted and if someone can insert a device between memory and CPU then they can get your decrypted data.

---

**If you control the operating system installed on a device**

You can encrypt the files, and then embed the decryption key into a [Trusted Platform Module (TPM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module).  By design the TPM should refuse to give the decryption key if the operating system is tampered with.  Then the operating system can be configured

It is possible to use a different encryption/decryption key for every device.  This might make users very unhappy, but it is possible to give the user a file that is encrypted for their (one) device and no other.

This would typically used [public/private key ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).  The advantage here is that there is no **root key** to steal which can decrypt every device.  The best someone could achieve would be to steal the decryption key for one device at a time (at considerable expense).

This would also let you send new (encrypted files) to users as long as you kept a record of their device's public key.

---

**If you can manufacture specialist hardware**

*Out of scope for this site but worth a mention*... It is possible to manufacture devices which decrypt and play on a single chip.  Worth mentioning are FPGAs which are programmable chips and *some* can be configured to prevent read-back.  This would let you create a player that could play encrypted files, with the decryption key embedded in it.  But because read-back can be disabled, you can prevent someone simply reading the decryption key or the decrypted file.

*Nothing is perfect, there are ways to reverse engineer what a microchip is doing internally.*